# What is the expected samba behaviour glusterfs 'distributed' volume cannot accessible?

Tags: samba4, glusterfs-3.5

What is the expected samba/ctdb behaviour when glusterfs distributed volume cannot accessible?

I have configured samba/ctdb over gluster "distributed" volume with three nodes. if one node goes down, what is the expected behaviour, can i still write on the samba share available from other two nodes?

Can you suggest any performance advice?

Comment: Why not test it out on a small model implementation before going into production?

Comment: Hello mdpc, I agree with you, we are in testing phase, we are going to move that in to production soon. however i have found that that i cannot write to CIFS when one gluster node goes down, I would like to get expert advice on this.